# Return a mapping in solidity

Tags: solidity, remix, erc-721

If I have a variable declaration such as follows:

`mapping(address => uint) public totalETHSpent;`

Is there any way for me to return the entire `mapping` object as-is via a `get()`. I see that in the docs, it mentions that this is not possible: https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.11/types.html?highlight=mapping#data-location

What other **GAS FRIENDLY** options do we have if I need to return a mapping of 10,000 entries?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using a loop function(ex.foor,while)

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.13;

contract Test2 {
    mapping(address => uint) public totalETHSpent;

    function getEThSpentByAddress(address[] calldata users) public view returns(uint256[] memory) {
      uint _length = users.length;
      uint[] memory results = new uint[](_length);

      for(uint i = 0; i < _length; i++) {
          results[i] = totalETHSpent[users[i]];
      }

      return results;
  }
}
```

You can modify the code to make the gas bill more effective.

- Reference : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4r20M9Fr8lY

But it looks like you really need a loop.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot, in general, get all the data out of a mapping. Let alone in a gas efficient way.

You will need to explain your use case and make some compromises.

Some options are:

- Track the information off-chain, send it on-chain and then confirm it on-chain.
- Double-account the information on-chain, once as a mapping and second for enumeration.

You can also study implementations of `ERC721Enumerable`, this is the first standardized approach to this problem. And I think Su Squares is the first project to actually implement this double accounting.